# Collecting websocket binary message chunks using WebSocketFrameAggregator from netty

Tags: java, websocket, netty

I'm trying to receive websocket binary message chunks from server and collect them together using **WebSocketFrameAggregator** with second netty **ChannelPipeline** configuration:

```
class BootstrapFactory {
public static final int MAX_FRAME_LENGTH = 8192;
public static final int TEN_MB = 10 * 1048576 ;

Bootstrap createBootstrap(final URI uri, final ChannelHandler handler) {
    return createBootstrap(uri, handler, null);
}

Bootstrap createBootstrap(final URI uri, final ChannelHandler handler, final SslHandler sslHandler) {
    final WebSocketClientHandshaker handshaker = WebSocketClientHandshakerFactory.newHandshaker(uri, WebSocketVersion.V13, null, false, new DefaultHttpHeaders());
    final WebSocketClientProtocolHandler wsHandler = new WebSocketClientProtocolHandler(handshaker);

    Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap()
            .group(new NioEventLoopGroup())
            .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
            .handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                @Override
                protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) {
                    ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
                    if (sslHandler != null) {
                        pipeline.addFirst(sslHandler);
                    }
                    pipeline.addLast(
                            new HttpClientCodec(),
                            new HttpObjectAggregator(MAX_FRAME_LENGTH),
                            wsHandler,
                            new WebSocketFrameAggregator(TEN_MB),
                            handler);
                }
            });
    return bootstrap;
}
}
```

In a result I get messages with limited size - max. 8192 bytes. Interesting thing is that when messages comes from server with size more than 8192 bytes, eg. 13786 bytes, in result WebSocketFrameAggregator return message with size of 5594 bytes which leads to losing some part of data.

Maybe some additional configuration is needed here? Need help. Thanks.

I'm using netty-all 4.1.0.Beta3 - and for some reason I can't change it to different version.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this problem using EmbeddedChannels, can you post a [mcve] containing the problem?

Comment: Frame sizes that you are testing with are smaller than default limit which is 65kB (at least in 4.1.1, I'm not sure about 4.1.0).

I had this issue with frame sizes over 100kB.
The solution involved two steps:
 - Add WebSocketFrameAggregator
 - Changing buffer limit (which is additional parameter when creating handshaker)